# Unexpected outcome when read right after write a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

Here is test code:

```py
FILE_PATH = "test.txt"
DEFAULT_TEXT = \
'''123456
456789'''

class FileTest:
    def __init__(self, file_path, default_text, desc):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.default_text = default_text
        self.desc = desc
    
    def __enter__(self):
        with open(self.file_path, "w") as f:
            f.write(self.default_text)
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('Test over.')
        print('--INFO--')
        print('Description:')
        print(self.desc)
        print('File content:')
        with open(self.file_path, "r") as f:
            print(f.read())
        print('--END--')


print('Default file content:')
print(DEFAULT_TEXT)

with FileTest(FILE_PATH, DEFAULT_TEXT, 'control'):
    with open(FILE_PATH, "r+") as f:
        _ = f.write("000")
        _ = f.readline()

with FileTest(FILE_PATH, DEFAULT_TEXT, 'use very small buffer'):
    with open(FILE_PATH, "r+", buffering=2) as f:
        _ = f.write("000")
        _ = f.readline()

with FileTest(FILE_PATH, DEFAULT_TEXT, 'do something between'):
    with open(FILE_PATH, "r+") as f:
        _ = f.write("000")
        _ = f.tell() # f.flush can work as well
        _ = f.readline()
```

Output:

```
Default file content:
123456
456789

Test over.
--INFO--
Description:
control
File content:
123456
456789000
--END--

Test over.
--INFO--
Description:
use very small buffer
File content:
000456
456789
--END--

Test over.
--INFO--
Description:
do something between
File content:
000456
456789
--END--
```

It means:
Default file content:
123456
456789

File content of control:
123456
456789000
Written at tail.

File content when use very small buffer:
000456
456789
Written at head.

File content when do something between:
000456
456789
Written at head.

I set a control to demonstrate the unexpected behaviour and 2 relieves that can correct the behaviour.
Doing something between read and write or set a very small buffer size can make the result correct.

Is this a bug of python? Or some feature of libc?